# Why accordion is not expanding or collapsing upon clicking?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

I have used this so I can expand and collapse the div upon clicking the + sign but it doesn't. It remains stiffed and doesn't expand or collapse. I tried adding and removing every unwanted script but still it doesn't work.
Also console has error:

**Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slideReveal is not a function**

```
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: -15px; height:52px;">

                        <div class="col-6 pt-3">
                            <h5 class="font-mobile">Planning Engineer</h5>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-6 pt-3" style="height:auto;">
                            <h5 class="mb-2 text-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    <h5>+</h5>
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body" style="height:auto;">
                            <h5 class="overflow-hidden mt-xs-2">Job Description:</h5>
                            <ul class="text-justify ul-xs">
                                <li>Prepare and update project schedule based on the contract.</li>
                                <li>Set work program and target milestones for each phase based on the project plan</li>
                                <li>Monitor critical activities based on the project schedule and advise project management.</li>
                                <li>Prepares and submit updated work program and cash flow curve showing actual progress and identify areas of weakness and establishes means and methods for recovery, if any, as well as new critical activities.</li>
                                <li>Monitor day to day work progress and prepare the weekly and monthly program and report.</li>
                                <li>Maintain and record update of work progress obtained from Project Manager.</li>
                                <li>Prepares monthly report reflecting work progress summary.</li>
                                <li>Provide process support to the other engineering disciplines</li>
                                <li>Provide specialist technical input into team project work</li>
                                <li>Develop or bring forward, as appropriate, industry best practices and new technologies.</li>
                                <li>Prepare and review project proposals, studies, and technical reports</li>
                                <li>Travel to sites as needed.</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h5> As our ideal candidate you will have:</h5>
                            <ul class="text-justify ul-xs">
                                <li>Bachelor or higher degree in Engineering</li>
                                <li>At least 7-8 years of experience in oil and gas sector.</li>
                                <li>Strong command on MS Project, MS excel and Primavera P6</li>
                                <li>Ability to communicate complex ideas effectively – both verbally and in writing – in English.</li>
                                <li>Outstanding record of academic achievement.</li>
                                <li>Ability to work effectively with people at all levels in an organization.</li>
                                <li>Excellent analytical and quantitative problem-solving skills.</li>
                                <li>Knowledge of International and Local applicable environmental laws and regulations.</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here's the source code of head being rendered.

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/C5D4D1E9-07CB-5B42-A8D8-EDAC580BC537/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script><script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W9FNBLV');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <!--  -->
    <!--    Document Title-->
    <!-- =============================================-->
    <!--<title>Velosi | Asset Integrity Ltd.</title>-->
    <title>Careers</title>

    <!--  -->
    <!--    JavaScripts-->
    <!--    =============================================-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/CustomEase.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/js/zanimation.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/lib/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <script src="/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/FixedHeader-3.1.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <script src="/Content/Theme/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/Theme/Toaster/toastr.js"></script>



    <!--    Favicons-->
    <!--    =============================================-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon.ico">

    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/Content/Theme/images/favicons/mstile-150x150.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!--  -->


    <!--    Stylesheets-->
    <!--    =============================================-->
    <!-- Default stylesheets-->
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Template specific stylesheets-->
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal-default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/lib/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/Toaster/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Main stylesheet and color file-->
    <link href="/Content/Theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/Theme/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <link href="/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/Theme/FixedHeader-3.1.4/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <link href="/Content/Theme/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Updated: I used it in this sequence but still not working.

```
 @*<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>*@

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Content/External/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    @*<script src="~/Content/External/js/popper.min.js"></script>*@
    @*<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/gsap/src/minified/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/CustomEase.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/js/config.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/js/zanimation.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/lightbox2/dist/js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/lib/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/js/core.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/External/js/jquery.slidereveal.min.js"></script>
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/FixedHeader-3.1.4/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Content/Theme/Toaster/toastr.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


    <!--    Favicons-->
    <!--    =============================================-->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/favicon.ico">
    @*<link rel="manifest" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/manifest.json">*@
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="~/Content/Theme/images/favicons/mstile-150x150.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <!--  -->
    <!--    Stylesheets-->
    <!--    =============================================-->
    <!-- Default stylesheets-->
    @*<link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">*@
    <!-- Template specific stylesheets-->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/loaders.css/loaders.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/iconsmind/iconsmind.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/External/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/hamburgers/dist/hamburgers.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    @*<link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">*@
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/remodal/dist/remodal-default-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/flexslider/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/lib/lightbox2/dist/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/Toaster/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Main stylesheet and color file-->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- DataTable -->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/FixedHeader-3.1.4/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/Responsive-2.2.2/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Datepicker -->
    <link href="~/Content/Theme/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: please create a code snippet or jsfiddle link. thank

Comment: your code is working fine [check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/q9mnay7k/1/) or can you show your inner html of head tag

Comment: maybe bootstrap issue, try using bootstrap CDN and new read new documentation

Comment: @JohnnyShallow [check this link](https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/q9mnay7k/2/) use the js link and css link as it is instead of your js and css which was commented.

Comment: I did, still not working

Comment: @UdhayTitus: check the updated code. I used it exactly in the sequence but not working. Please check

Comment: is it possible to add snippet here

Comment: full code? ok i will

Comment: @UdhayTitus: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1iHLpbsLJfoUZ32tQSPiYCAPGusLgU-9X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add extra `data-parent="#accordion"` attribute in `<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">` line. I just removed this attribute in a below code snippet. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: -15px; height:52px;">

            <div class="col-6 pt-3">
                <h5 class="font-mobile">Planning Engineer</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 pt-3" style="height:auto;">
                <h5 class="mb-2 text-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <h5>+</h5>
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="card-body" style="height:auto;">
                <h5 class="overflow-hidden mt-xs-2">Job Description:</h5>
                <ul class="text-justify ul-xs">
                    <li>Prepare and update project schedule based on the contract.</li>
                    <li>Set work program and target milestones for each phase based on the project plan</li>
                    <li>Monitor critical activities based on the project schedule and advise project management.</li>
                    <li>Prepares and submit updated work program and cash flow curve showing actual progress and identify areas of weakness and establishes means and methods for recovery, if any, as well as new critical activities.</li>
                    <li>Monitor day to day work progress and prepare the weekly and monthly program and report.</li>
                    <li>Maintain and record update of work progress obtained from Project Manager.</li>
                    <li>Prepares monthly report reflecting work progress summary.</li>
                    <li>Provide process support to the other engineering disciplines</li>
                    <li>Provide specialist technical input into team project work</li>
                    <li>Develop or bring forward, as appropriate, industry best practices and new technologies.</li>
                    <li>Prepare and review project proposals, studies, and technical reports</li>
                    <li>Travel to sites as needed.</li>
                </ul>
                <h5> As our ideal candidate you will have:</h5>
                <ul class="text-justify ul-xs">
                    <li>Bachelor or higher degree in Engineering</li>
                    <li>At least 7-8 years of experience in oil and gas sector.</li>
                    <li>Strong command on MS Project, MS excel and Primavera P6</li>
                    <li>Ability to communicate complex ideas effectively – both verbally and in writing – in English.</li>
                    <li>Outstanding record of academic achievement.</li>
                    <li>Ability to work effectively with people at all levels in an organization.</li>
                    <li>Excellent analytical and quantitative problem-solving skills.</li>
                    <li>Knowledge of International and Local applicable environmental laws and regulations.</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are trying to execute the method before the DOM is safe to be manipulated. The underlying issue is that you've put all your script tags in the `head` tag and not after the body content. Try wrapping your call in the following:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
})
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Unrelated to the problem, but some feedback would be to reduce the number of resources being requested on the page by bundling them. This can have a significant impact on the load time for the end user.

Comment: which scripts should I put after body tag?

Comment: All scripts, unless otherwise recommended by the provider such as google analytics, should go at the end of the body content (not body tag).